# Shopping Basket indexOf

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am trying to use indexOf to determine if the obj I am passing it is already within the array. It does not seem to work. Here is the code for adding the item to the array.

Javascript:

```
add: function(id, item, description, price, itemObj) {
            if(items.indexOf(itemObj) == 1) {
                console.log(itemObj);
                items.forEach(function(item){
                    if(item.id === id){
                        item.itemCount += 1;
                    };
                });
            } else {
                console.log(itemObj);
                items.push(new basket.Item(id, item, description, price));
            };
            basket.print();
        }
```

To be more descriptive, it will never run the if statement and will always resort to passing a new object to the array.

Comment: You have item in the calling function and use items below in a manner that would be inconsistent with the call.

Comment: Sorry could you explain this?

Comment: You've got function(id, `item`, description ... further in the code you are using `item` **s** rather than item for indexOf and forEach with `item` inside the foreach function.

Comment: items is not the same as item. items is a global array that is getting checked where as item is a variable being passed into the method.

Comment: Got it ... working with the code I see.  Global items can confuse things.

Comment: I think I should rename the variables to be honest.

Comment: I was just going to ask if you wanted to compare against "1" since indexOf returns an index ...

Comment: As stated above, `indexOf()` returns an index if the element was found and `-1` otherwise. You need to check the result against `-1`, for example: `if (items.indexOf(itemObj) != -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if indexOf looks for matching a value in an array. I think it just matchs a substring inside a string. Plus, you should check if the returned value is greater or equal zero:

```
if(items.join("").indexOf(itemObj) >= 0) {
```

Well, the join function concatenates the values to build a string, example:

```
items = ["first", "second", "third"];

items.join("");

// now items = "firstsecondthird";

var ind = items.join("").indexOf("first"); //ind here is greater or equal than 0

var ind = items.join("").indexOf("firstone"); //ind here is equal -1 (any comparison in the string)
```

Be aware that indexOf is searching for the first comparison in the string. If you have this string `abcdefga` and you looking for `a` with `indexOf`, the returned value will be 0 because the first comparison is at the beginning. To search for the last comparison would be `lastIndexOf`.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit better?

Comment: This answer is wrong - `Array.prototype.indexOf()` indeed exists (though it is unavailable in some older browsers), and the proposed solution works only against string matching, as `items.join("")` will first convert each element of the array to a string. In case of objects, it would probably be `[object Object]`, so it wouldn't be too useful.

Comment: First: I didn't know `items` was a collection of objects. Second: I started my answer saying "I'm not sure if indexOf looks for matching a value in an array". I'm just trying to help.